# Alternate expression for subu in MIPS

Tags: mips

I was wondering if there was an alternate way to express the "subu" command in MIPS?

Comment: Of course there are, do you want to actually know them too? Actually I suspect you already know some

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know them..